Unable to delete several keyboard layouts
I have Windows 11 Pro with five keyboard layouts:

I want to remove the last two of them. They are not displayed in the list of available languages:
enter image description here
They are also not visible in regedit:

This is my welcome screen and new user settings, so still not visible:

Could you please tell me how to remove them?

Try adding the keyboard then removing it as suggested by an answer to the duplicate
